# Ansible-builder - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: linux, pip, ansible, debian, ansible-awx

I needed to create a custom image for AWX so that I can add external python modules to my ansible playbooks. I installed ansible-builder to do that but I'm getting the following error for any commands I try to run with ansible-builder :

```
me@ansible:~$ ansible-builder --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-builder", line 7, in <module>
    from ansible_builder.cli import run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible_builder/cli.py", line 104
    help=f'The name(s) for the container image being built (default: {constants.default_tag})')
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I installed it on debian 9 like so :

```
pip install ansible-builder
```

I tried to install it with pip and pip3, my user and root but I'm getting the same error everytime.

Comment: https://ansible-builder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/ `ansible-builder` version 1.1.0 **requires Python 3.8 or higher**. https://pypi.org/project/ansible-builder/3.0.0/ **requires Python >= 3.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f-strings` only became available in python 3.6 ([PEP-498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) and you are using python 3.5 (from your traceback: `"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible_builder/cli.py"`), so you have a version incompatibility.

You will need to update to a more recent python version. Even the oldest `ansible-builder` release [on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-builder/0.1.0/) requires `Python >=3.6, <4.0`